# How to create unittest for private generic method in c# ex private string FindColumn<T>

Tags: c#, .net, api, unit-testing

I have a method

```
private string FindColumn<T>(string sortColumn, string sortDirection = "asc")
{}
```

My TestMethod

```
var result = _privateObject.Invoke("FindColumn<SelectListModel>", new object[] {sortColumn, sortDirection});
```

It cannot work.
Could someone please help me to check my syntax.

Thanks,
Dam Tran

Comment: How can I pass "<SelectListModel>" to call method?

Comment: Typically, testing private members are avoided. That being said you would have to use reflection to get the member and then give it the generic member before trying to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no way around using reflection here.

1. Get the `MethodInfo` object of the method that you want to test. For that, you have to pass special binding flags as the reflection API usually ignores private members.
2. Instantiate the generic method using the `MakeGenericMethod` method. Here, you pass your generic type parameters as `Type` objects that you can get via the `typeof()` operator
3. The resulting `MethodInfo` object has an `Invoke` method that you can call

However, the much better solution is usually to redesign your classes for testability such that you can access these methods more easily: I am not sure the next guy will understand what you did in the tests, if you don't write a good documentation why you needed to test a private method.